# How can I write the equation for a tensor dot product?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I wrote some code and now I'm trying to turn it into an equation. There is a vector $v$ of size $k$ and a matrix $\mathbf{M}$ of size $k \times n_1 \times n_2$. My code works like this:

```
M_2d = M.reshape(k, n1 * n2)
W_1d = v.dot(M_reshaped)
W = W_1d.reshape(n1, n2)
```

Is there someway to write the equation for the computation of W using tensor notation? I think this is just a tensor dot-product but I'm not sure how to notate it.

Comment: Could you give us some hint about what this language is or do we have to guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the $1$-mode tensor product of a tensor $M\in\mathbb{R}^{j\times n_1\times n_2}$ with a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^j$. Elementwise:
$$\left(M \times_1 v\right)_{i_2 i_3}=\sum_{i_1=1}^k M_{ i_1 i_2 i_3}\,v_{i_1}$$

See e.g. [Tensor decompositions](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/07070111X) or the [Matlab tensor classes](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1186785.1186794).